# Как правильно сформулировать одно из положений договора?

Tags: грамотная-речь, лексика, выбор-слов

> Оплатить разницу между произведённой им предварительной оплаты за два и более семестров

или

> Оплатить разницу между произведённой им оплатой за два и более семестры

Comment: Вы бы рассказали своими словами, что означает эта формулировка. Между чем и чем разница? Между оплатой за два семестра и стоимостью всех семестров?

Comment: Предполагаю, автор привел только часть предложения. чем поставил отвечающих  в положение гадалок. Вопрос должен быть дополнен.

Comment: Может быть, вопрос и должен быть дополнен, но не факт, что автор его дополнит. Это далеко не первый случай, когда содержание вопросов приходится "додумывать", а здесь как раз ничего сложного  нет.   Ключевые слова - предварительная оплата и разница, что еще между представить, кроме разницы между предварительной оплатой и фактической стоимостью.

Comment: Что имеется в виду: a) нужно доплатить за два и более семестров (с учётом ранее внесённого аванса) или б) плата за два и более семестров уже была внесена, и нужно оплатить разницу с требуемой суммой, напр. в результате повышения цен?

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Answer (score 0):

Ответ исправлен

1) **Правильный выбор падежа существительного  после предлога МЕЖДУ**

Предлог МЕЖДУ управляет Т.п. (между оплатой).

**МЕЖДУ**, предлог. **кем-чем**, (разг.) кого-чего.

Значение 5. Указывает на группу лиц, **предметов**, явлений и т.п., которые сравниваются, сопоставляются друг с другом. Изучать различия м. животным и растительным миром. **Не видеть разницы м. двумя породами лошадей.**

2) **Правильный выбор формы существительного (за два и более семестра):**

Розенталь: http://www.evartist.narod.ru/text1/59.htm

6. В сочетаниях два (три, четыре) и более... управляемое существительное ставится **в родительном падеже единственного числа: два и более варианта,** три и более трудных формы, четыре и более ценных предложения, т.е. существительное ставится в зависимость от числительных два, три, четыре, а не от слова более (ср. возможность перестановки: два варианта и более).

3) **И редактирование:**

**Оплатить разницу между произведённой им предварительной оплатой и фактической стоимостью обучения за два и более семестра.**

Comment: _... **между** произведённой им предварительной **оплаты**_... — не могу понять смысл предложения, но последнее слово в родительном падеже выглядит подозрительно.

Comment: Я думаю, что вопрос касался именно этого падежа. И творительный падеж во втором варианте выглядит лучше, даже если не понимать смысл сказанного.

Comment: @grizzly тут все настолько запущено, что падежом одного слова не отделаешься. Посмотрите мой ответ, быть может, я понял ситуацию лучше.

Answer (score 0):

Более правильно, думаю, так:

*Оплатить разницу между произведённой им предварительной оплат**ой** за два и более семестр**а**.*

Тут так. Что такое разница между оплатой (и чем-то там еще) - это вещь в принципе понимаемая. А вот разница "между оплаты" - это совсем не по-русски. Хотя и этот вариант - тоже не подарок, грамматика менее страдает, но смысл остается непонятным.

Допускаю, что в исходном тексте пропущено слово "сумма" или подобное. 
Тогда имеем:

*Оплатить разницу между суммой произведённой им предварительной оплат**ы** за два и более семестр**а**.*

Дальше править сложно не зная ситуативного контекста, но если попітаься домыслить, то в хорошем стиле это будет звучать примерно так.

***Обязать студента платной формы обучения Имярекова И. И. возместить разницу между суммой предварительной оплаты за два и более семестра и фактической стоимостью полученных им образовательных услуг.***

Comment: По-моему, **возмещают** ущерб, а разница в данном случае ущербом не является.

Answer (score 0):

**Оплатить разницу между произведённой им предварительной оплаты за два и более семестров** 
Между чем? 
1) Оплатить разницу между семестрами. 
2) Оплатить разницу между оплатами за два и более семестров (семестра). 
Без "между": 
3) Оплатить разницу произведённой оплаты за два и более семестров (семестра); 
Но! Оплатить разницу оплаты? Видимо, "оплаты" нужно заменить на другое слово или исключить.