# Разницу оплачивают или платят?

Tags: грамотная-речь, лексическая-сочетаемость

Мой вопрос навеян ответами на другой вопрос: [Как правильно сформулировать одно из положений договора?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/441470/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d1%81%d1%84%d0%be%d1%80%d0%bc%d1%83%d0%bb%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b0)

Я был уверен, что нельзя писать "оплатить разницу". И ответ Грамоты это подтверждает:

> Вопрос № 287512
>   В каких случаях употребляется слово "оплатить", а в каком "уплатить"?
>   **Ответ справочной службы русского языка**
>   Оплатить – то, за что платят: учебу, поездку, лечение, услуги... Уплатить – то, что платят: взнос, штраф, пени...

Но вот цитата из Гражданского кодекса, которая противиречит такому пониманию:

> 2. В случае, когда в соответствии с договором мены обмениваемые товары признаются неравноценными, сторона, обязанная передать товар, цена которого ниже цены товара, предоставляемого в обмен, должна **оплатить разницу** в ценах непосредственно до или после исполнения ее обязанности передать товар, если иной порядок оплаты не предусмотрен договором. [Гражданский кодекс Российской Федерации. Часть вторая (1995) // , 2004]

Может разгадка здесь:

> Вопрос № 289122
>   Здравствуйте. Корректно ли выражение "стоимость оплачивается, оплатить стоимость" и т.п. словообразования? Заранее благодарю.
>   **Ответ справочной службы русского языка**
>   Корректно. Оплатить стоимость = отдать деньги в возмещение величины затрат на что-либо.

Значит, оплатить — это еще и отдать деньги в возмещение чего-либо? Значит,  корректно говороть: оплатить разницу, оплать долг? При этом разница и долг — это нечто, что нужно возместить?

Но нет, пожалуй. Стиимость из вопроса — это "определённое количество общественно необходимого труда, затраченного на производство товара и овеществлённого, воплощённого в этом товаре". То есть оплатить стоимость = оплатить труд. А оплатить разницу?

Вот еще нашел (теперь недоступно):

> О глаголе «оплатить» мы уже достаточно подробно поговорили в одном из предыдущих выпусков, а вот «уплатить» упустили из виду, и зря. Дело в том, что, несмотря на кажущуюся синонимичность этих двух слов, между ними есть существенная разница в употреблении. Оплатить используется в случаях, когда речь идёт о том, за что платят: товар, проезд, коммунальные услуги, выставленный счёт и тому подобное. Его часто можно сравнить с глаголом «получать». Я оплатил (заплатил за что?) проживание в гостинице. Уплатить — когда речь идёт о том, что платят (об эквиваленте денег): пошлина, штраф, комиссионные, квартплата, выкуп и так далее. Это слово, наоборот, по значению ближе к «отдавать». Я уплатил (заплатил что?) членские взносы.
>   Некоторые слова (например, долг) не трактуются однозначно, в их отношении применимы оба глагола, в зависимости от ситуации. Он мог порадовать немного детей и сделать подарки своей бедной жене, принесшей ему в жертву свою молодость, чтобы помочь ему оплатить долги чести (Ф. Достоевский). Стремись уплатить свой долг, и ты достигнешь двоякой цели, ибо тем самым его исполнишь (К. Прутков).

Запутался я. Помогите разобраться.

Answer (score 2):

Предлагаю рассмотреть **следующую таблицу** (она составлена в соответствии с реальным употреблением глаголов):

По горизонтали три глагола: ***заплатить, уплатить, оплатить.***

По вертикали три позиции: ***деньги, счёт (эквивалент денег), предмет/услуга.***

1) **ДЕНЬГИ**   ***заплатил*** 1000 рублей;     ***уплатил*** 1000 рублей.

2) **СЧЁТ (ЭКВИВАЛЕНТ ДЕНЕГ)**  ***заплатил*** взносы/штраф; ***уплатил*** взносы/штраф;    ***оплатил*** взносы/штраф/счет/иск,

***заплатил*** (деньги) по счету,  ***уплатил*** (деньги) по счету.

3) **ПРЕДМЕТ/УСЛУГА**   ***заплатил за*** квартиру/ремонт;      ***уплатил за*** квартиру/ремонт;   ***оплатил*** квартиру/ремонт.

**Ответ на вопрос:**

**Можно оплатить разницу/задолженность,**  глагол ***оплатить*** универсальный (нельзя оплатить только деньги).

**Разница** ― это нечто среднее между предметом и счетом. Поэтому лучше оплатить разницу, а не заплатить разницу или уплатить разницу (эти выражения употребляются, но скорее относятся к разговорной речи).

Comment: Интересный подход. Но вопросы есть.  Вы видите различие между  разницей между двумя выплатами и, скажем, дополнительной платой? Оба - ЭКВИВАЛЕНТ ДЕНЕГ?

Comment: Приведите, пожалуйста, примеры предложений, а то вопрос не очень ясен.

Comment: _Разница в ценах_ (как в примере из вопроса) - это _столько-то рублей_. Поэтому её можно выплатить или вернуть (по контексту - из денег, уже уплаченных покупателем), но не оплатить.

Comment: Исходное предложение: "Оплатить разницу между произведённой им предварительной оплатой (и фактической стоимостью обучения) за два и более семестра. Если обучение оплачивается предварительно, то вы или переплатили или недоплатили  (я реально сталкивалась со вторым вариантом). Вам должны  вернуть переплату,  или вы  должны оплатить разницу. Оба варианта встречаются в текстах.

Comment: "Когда речь заходит о внедрении инновационных материалов, возникает два главных вопроса: насколько это дороже аналогов и готов ли потребитель оплатить разницу"?  http://search1.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%EE%EF%EB%E0%F2%E8%F2%FC+%F0%E0%E7%ED%E8%F6%F3 В настоящее время орган местного самоуправления ведёт тяжбу с продавцом и намерен вернуть «переплату» за приобретённые для сирот квартиры.

Answer (score 1):

Глагол **оплатить** употребляется также в таких случаях:

> Оплатить ... // Уплатить какую-л. сумму денег в погашение чего-л. О. счёт. О.
>   задолженность. О. квитанцию. О. телефонные переговоры. Оплатил
>   пребывание в гостинице.

Как раз наш случай: оплатить разницу между... = уплатить сумму денег в погашение разницы между...

Можно **уплатить** по счёту или по квитанции, и даже **уплатить** задолженность, но выражение "уплатить разницу" мне нравится меньше.

Замечу отдельно, что пограничные тонкости в употреблении разных глаголов "оплаты" вызывают споры среди специалистов, о чём на нашем форуме уже упоминалось.

**Дополнение**. Просто несколько разнообразных цитат. Выбирал издания получше и годы понадёжнее.

> В том случае, когда стоимость товара превышает предельную сумму
>   кредита, покупатель должен оплатить разницу между стоимостью... (Новое
>   в жизни, науке, технике: Серия Экономика, 1983)
>
> ...Пассажир должен оплатить разницу расстояния по общему тарифу...
>   (Комментарий к Уставу железных дорог СССР, 1986)
>
> ...Если покупатель не согласится оплатить разницу во фрахте...
>   (Организация и техника внешней торговли СССР, 1974)
>
> ...Согласен оплатить разницу в арендной плате... (Иностранная
>   литература, 1970)

И так далее.

Comment: По-моему, речь идет о разнице между двумя величинами в рублях. Это некая сумма денег, которую нужно просто отдать. Другое дело задолженность. Это некое состояния, которое нужно ликвидировать (погасить). Таким образом,  задолженность оплатим (раз уж словарь так говорит), а разницу заплатим (отдадим). Согласны?

Comment: @М_Г Моё чувство языка никогда с таким употреблением не согласится :) Сейчас я дополню свой ответ цитатами. Интересно, сможет ли кто-то найти цитату с "уплатить разницу".

Comment: придется только **уплатить разницу** между долгом и «справедливой оценкой». [Стенограммы заседаний Государственной Думы 29 марта 1907 г. Заседание восемнадцатое. Продолжение прений по аграрному вопросу (1907)]

Comment: Ты, мол, дура такая, в тетрадку не заглянула, цену не проверила. **Плати разницу**. Тут же на счетчик поставили, расписки отобрали. [Виктор Мясников. Водка (2000)]

Comment: За первое спасибо, а самиздат я бы постеснялся цитировать :) Про стенограммы не знаю, правили ли в них ошибки, или записывали как есть?

Comment: Министерство финансов должно будет **заплатить разницу** в ценах, торговых и сметных; войска же недоумевали, почему им в таких же ценах отказали, а все заготовление затягивалось, и нижние чины претендовали, что им не дают обещанного, и все это только для того, чтобы обманно уменьшить на несколько миллионов предстоявшие расходы и неизбежный дефицит по смете на 1906 год! [А. Ф. Редигер. История моей жизни (1918)]

Comment: Все цитаты - из Нацкорпуса. Его создатели не постеснялись...

Comment: Да, я тоже нашёл нормальные примеры. Значит в прошлый раз что-то сделал не так в поиске. Тогда, возможно, оба варианта допустимы. Я смягчил свой ответ.

Comment: По поводу примеров из ответа. "Оплатить разницу расстояния", "оплатить разницу во фрахте" — понятно, здесь оплачивается расстояние, фрахт (как груз). А вот другие разницы — это суммы денег, не пойму, почему деньги оплачивают деньгами.

Answer (score 1):

**Оплатить** здесь употреблено, как и положено, в качестве *переходного* глагола. Но нужно разобраться с *предметом* оплаты. Оплачивают нечто, сделанное одной стороной для другой стороны (работа, услуга, товар). Оплата получаемых благ производится в форме, имеющей размерность (деньги) и размер (их согласованное или запрошенное количество). В контексте явно названного "блага" (оплатить работу, услугу, товар), предоставленного одной стороной, ему приравнивается сумма денег, выплачиваемая другой стороной. Такое *приравнивание разнородных сущностей* и приводит к "**оплате (блага)**". В обезличенных же контекстах, где фигурируют деньги, их просто "**платят**" или (однократно) "**уплачивают**", как бы ни назывались сущности, имеющие исключительно денежное выражение: **штраф, налог, (денежный) долг** (видимо, возможно "оплатить чужой долг" - как услугу прощения долга должнику). Сюда приходится отнести и "разницу" *в суммах денег* как *причитающуюся плату* (за что-то): **заплатить разницу между одной и другой суммой денег**. Если же эта разница не обезличена (приводится не в деньгах, а в количестве фактически поставленного товара), то можно говорить об *оплате разницы в количестве товара*, но для "количества семестров" такое нетипично, поэтому в нашем случае выходит ответ "**нельзя**".

Comment: Alex_ander Ваш ход мыслей мне близок и понятен. Однако Вы никак не комментируете цитату из Гражданского кодекса,  которая нашим выводам противоречит.

Comment: Думаю, что верно было бы "**выплатить** разницу в ценах" (это буквально количество денег)  или "оплатить излишние расходы (понесённые потребителем в результате такой замены)".

Answer (score 0):

Спасибо всем, кто ответил на мой вопрос. Осмысливая все ответы (а авторы не во всем согласны друг с другом), я построил для себя такую модель.

1. Нужно принять тот факт, что кроме основного смысла слова **оплатить** ("Оплатить – то, за что платят: учебу, поездку, лечение, услуги"), есть еще и дополнительный — **погасить** (задолженность, штраф и т. п.). За что-то или в погашение чего-то мы **платим** деньги.
2. Есть слова, смысл которых можно понимать двояко. Например, обнаружена разница между стоимостью и фактически произведенной оплатой. С одной стороны, это сумма денег, математическая разность двух чисел, выраженная  в рублях, ее **платят**. С другой стороны, это некая задолженность, которую **оплачивают** (погашают). В источниках преобладает выражение *оплатить разницу*.

Comment: Мне кажется, что всё намного проще. Есть видовая пара платить - заплатить/уплатить.Платим (что) деньги за что (за вещи и услуги). Есть особый глагол оплатить  (вещи, услуги), глагол универсален (приставка О охватывает любой предмет, кроме денег), мы оплачиваем всё: предметы, услуги, квитанции, счета, разницу в том числе. Кроме денег, можем заплатить/уплатить штраф  (это те же деньги), а вот заплатить/уплатить счет и квитанцию не можем (это бумага).  Заплатить разницу можно, но с натяжкой (только в разговорной речи).

Comment: Это реальная сочетаемость слов. Если сочетание незнакомо, то важно определиться: предмет или деньги и потом проверить его на слух.